# iopus / imacro - Log errors to file

Tags: macros, automation, imacros

I'm writing an imacro script to automate tasks on firefox. The script works fine but sometimes it doesn't find the correct html.
How can I log to a txt file every time the script encounters an error?

Sample script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !TIMEOUT 4
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE c:\myfile.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ID:form0 ATTR=ID:Email CONTENT={{!COL1}} //lets assume the error is here, how can I log it ?
 SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:Passwd CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:form2 ATTR=ID:PersistentCookie CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form3 ATTR=ID:signIn
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use profiler:
http://wiki.imacros.net/Performance_Profiler

other option is to convert your code to javascript or similar format and catch and save thrown errors::
http://wiki.imacros.net/Error_and_Return_Codes

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I would like to add a custom var to the error log and it doesn't seem to be possible without converting the code to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
SET !FILE_PROFILER myprofile.xml
```

documented here: http://wiki.imacros.net/Performance_Profiler

..and than you have to write yourself a script that looks for errors in this file.